# What animal does this foot skeleton belong to?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

I found an articulated foot skeleton. Sun bleached. What animal is this likely from?

[image]

Comment: Where was it found (in the world; there are people here from many different countries), what sort of environment (hill, beach, river etc.) and some sense of size will help with ID

Comment: Please see the species ID guidelines to improve your post: https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info